# Orphaned SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.* queue in Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, durable-subscription

I have a queue 'SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.ABCD***109' getting messages all the time and no one to consume it.
I tried to get its subscription but got the following result ,

```
dis sub(*) where (DEST LK 'SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.ABCD***109')   

AMQ8096: IBM MQ subscription inquired.
   SUBID(414D5120******************44A0109)
   SUB(false)
   DEST(SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.ABCD***44A0108)
```

then i tried to view the subscription via the subscription id listed,

```
     dis sbstatus(*) where ( SUBID EQ '414D5120***44A0109')
AMQ8099: IBM MQ subscription status inquired.
   SUB(false)
   SUBID(414D5120***44A0109)
```

I don't have a subscription named "false" . I'm unable to clear or delete this queue as it is opened. I'm unable to view the open connection as well.

```
    dis conn(*) where (objname eq 'SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.ABCD***44A0108')
AMQ8461: Connection identifier not found.
```

I need to cleanup & delete this queue to avoid disk space issue.

Comment: Could you add what version and platform of MQ you were using when you saw the SUB(false) and could you confirm that the output above was seen using the runmqsc tool (that's what it looks like but I'd rather not guess). Is this behaviour - the SUB(false) - recreatable? I'd like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I agree about the SUB(false), the commands I added to my Answer should provide you internally what MQ thinks the SUB name is.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove SUB objects with only the SUBID, try to remove it with this command:

```
DELETE SUB SUBID('414D5120***44A0109')
```

Note that the command is not specifying the SUB name, just the SUB keyword.

---

Before you delete it, if you are interested in seeing what the sub name actually is, you may want to try running the following command to dump the subscriptions:

```
amqldmpa -m <QueueManager> -c T -f /var/mqm/errors/amqldmpa_topic.out
```

Inside of the file `/var/mqm/errors/amqldmpa_topic.out` search for the SUBID in question and look for text similar to this:

```
Subscriber entry
{
  SubId ( 414D5120***44A0109)
  SubNameString ( SUBNAME_HERE )
  TopicString ( TOPIC/STRING/HERE )
   <more lines of information go here>
}
```

What does it show for the `SubNameString` field?  Note that in the 8.0.0.6 version I ran this against it seems to pad each field with a leading and trailing space with the exception of SubId which did not have a trailing space.

Comment: The fact that it displays SUB(false) sounds defective don't you think?

Comment: @MoragHughson I agree it is strange.  If he opened a PMR with IBM they would likely want a MQ trace and maybe the output of amqldmpa.